# Main storyboard resizing glitch (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Xcode fails to resize the view controllers properly.

Examples:

[In this link, some view controllers are sized as iPhone 4s, some are iPhone 7.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTd0n.png)

[In this link, all view controllers load properly when iPhone 4s is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIk5M.png)

I have already quit and restarted Xcode multiple times, and I just restarted my computer, but the issue is still there.

Comment: It looks like you don't have your constraints setup to handle different sizes. The screen is taller on the iPhone7 than it is on the 4s, so you have to design your layout to adjust to the different heights (and widths). *Edit* or, sorry... do you mean ***in Interface Builder*** the actual frames of the views are not resizing?

Comment: Is it possible you set the "Simulated Size" to `Freeform` at some point and forgot to change it back to `Fixed`?